# Apache Airflow - Run task on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow

We're considering migrating our data pipelines to Airflow and one item we require is the ability for a task to create, execute on, and destroy an EC2 instance. I know that Airflow supports ECS and Fargate which will have a similar effect, but not all of our tasks will fit directly into that paradigm without significant refactoring.

I see that we can use a distributed executor and scale the pool of workers up and down manually, but we really don't need to have workers up all the time, only occasionally, and when we do we're just as well served by having a dedicated machine for each task as it runs, destroying each machine as the task completes.

The idea I have stuck in my head would be something like a "EphemeralEC2Operator", which would stand up a machine, SSH in, run a bash script which orchestrates the task, and then tear the machine down.

Does this capability exist, or would we have to implement it ourselves?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not think there's anything like that publicly available. gcloud does: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/gcp/compute.html#gceinstancestartoperator.  You could probably create one without too much trouble.

I'm curious why you can't squeeze your tasks into ecs?

Comment: I suggest, you create custom AirFlow operator which creates, executes and destroys. This link can help you to get the code snippets  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707594/airflow-luigi-for-aws-emr-automatic-cluster-creation-and-pyspark-deployment

Comment: @RobertMoskal most tasks are actually already in Docker, but there's usually a bash script wrapping them which handles some setup, parameters, other services, pull data down from S3, etc. Any number of things. We'd rather only change one thing at once while migrating, if possible.

Comment: @RangaVure, thanks for the link. It will be helpful!

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to move that script into the containers!